# Force parent class to call an overriden methon in child class

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

In a parent class, one method calls the other. The first method is the same in a child class, but the second method is overridden.

```
class Parent():
    def method1(self):
        self.method2

    def method2(self):
        # Some code

class Child(Parent):
    def method1(self)
        super().method1()

    def method2(self):
        # Some other code
```

When I call super().method1() in a child class, can I force the parent class to call the overridden method in the child?

Comment: What do you actually want to do? If you want the child class to only run its overriden method, you can just remove the call to `super().method1()`

Comment: The parent class knows nothing about its children

Comment: I actually have some code in method 1 in the parent class. It divides data into parts, then calls method 2 for each partition. The data division rule is the same in a child class, but the algorithm applied to each partition is different. Sure, I can simply remove ```super().method1()```, but it would yield a code duplication that I am trying to avoid.

Comment: Then it looks like you should have a function in parent that only does data partition, another one for algorithm and one that run both successively if you want, then the child would have one for the algorithm, and the one that runs both successively would call the parent data division function
In short: divide into even more functions

Comment: @Gugu72 I came up with this idea, too. And it seems the only possible way. It would just take some refactoring, since in the project things are a bit more complicated than depicted in a topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to override `method1`. `self.method2()` does just a normal Python attribute lookup on `self`. So , it will find the `method2` implementation of `self`'s most concrete class first:

```
class Parent:
    def method1(self):
        self.method2()

    def method2(self):
        # Some code

class Child(Parent):
    def method2(self):
        # Some other code
```

Comment: So calling ```Child().method1()``` shall work?

Comment: Yes. That will automatically call the child class's `method2`. Otherwise software design would be rather tedious. That's the whole point of using inheritence and providing hooks such as `method2` for subclasses to override.

Comment: Thank you! I know there is gotta be a simple yet elegant solution